# Porque no puedo generar un archivo pdf en flask

Tags: python, pdf, flask

Esto es lo que tengo en mi código, ya hice la instalación del pdfkit y lo importe también estoy siguiendo ejemplos y documentación pero me aparece este error:

```
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

Pero también tengo ya instalado el wktohtmlpdf en mi pc y en la carpeta con el binario junto con el PATH, pero a pesar de eso me sigue saliendo el error y no tengo ni idea de como resolverlo.

Esto es lo que tengo en la función

```py
@app.route('/certificadoPDF/<name>/<ubi>')
def certificadoPDF(name, ubi):
        rendered = render_template('certificadoAsisPDF.html', name=name, ubi=ubi)
        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)
        response = make_response(pdf)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=salida.pdf'
        return response
```

Esto en el html que quiero que se genere

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<header>
    <!-- Menú -->
</header>

<body>
    <h2 style="color: white;">-</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 style="color: black;">Prueba</h2>
        <hr>
        <h2>Hola {{ name }}</h2><br>
        <h2>Estas en {{ ubi }}</h2>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque lo tengas instalado, lo más seguro es que no lo tengas agregado al PATH, o al menos no correctamente, en principio debería agregarse a la variable de entorno `PATH` algo como:

> "ruta\a\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"'

o también puedes especificar la ruta a dicho ejecutable de forma explícita [[1](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit#configuration)]:

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='ruta/a/wkhtmltopdf.exe')
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, configuration=config)
```

obviamente ésto deberás corregirlo cuando despliegues el código en un servidor en producción.

---

1. [Repsitorio Oficial en GitHub de python-pdfkit - Configuration](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit#configuration).

Comment: Gracias ya no me presenta ese error pero por algún motivo no me genera el pdf, se ejecuta la funcion pero no pasa nada